fresh install: unable to access new partition or even run any apps
Did a fresh install of 22.04 LTS and I can't do anything at all with it because of permissions.
From Konsole, I type "firefox" and get
mount -t tmpfs /tmp/snap.rootfs_LAPr43
and Firefox doesn't start. I can't install Chromium - or anything else for that matter. Gets a very similar error.
I've no idea what to do next.

"Konsole" suggests that you installed Kubuntu 22.04. FYI: Support for Kubuntu 22.04 ends in April 2025, six months from now.

Version stated in my post. You're right, though, Kubuntu. Any insight on the error message? I spent quite a while searching and didn't find anything helpful.
